# Writing the collection of all linear relations between the vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad v_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3\\
5\\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad v_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
8\\
13\\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad v_4 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5\\
8\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The Question is asking to "Write the collection of all linear relations between the following collecitons of vectors?

I reduced the vectors to row echleon form which came out to be

$$ \text{Row Echleon } =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&1 &0\\
0&1&2&1& 0\\
0&0&0&0 &0\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

And i figured out they are all linearly dependant, and this is where I am right now.. I just don't get the question.

Comment: What does "they *all* are lin. dependent" mean? A set of vectors is either linearly dep. or not. Since clearly $\;v_3=v_1+2v_2\;$, the given set of vectors is dependent...yet, for example, $\;\{v_1,v_2\}\;$ is linearly *independent*

Answer (score 1):

The columns of your reduced matrix represent the same vectors, just in a different basis. Thus we can read off all relations from the reduced matrix we see

$$v_3=v_1+2v_2$$
and 
$$v_4=v_1+v_2$$

(Of course there are an infinite number of relations:
$$26v_1+33v_2-7v_3-10v_4=0)$$

But the collection of all relations is

$$a(v_1+2v_2-v_3)+b(v_1+v_2-v_4)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

We have to  search four numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that:
$av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4=0$ and this is the same as solve the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b+3c+2d=0\\
2a+3b+8c+5d=0\\
3a+5b+13c+8d=0
\end{cases}
$$
the solution can be write as:

$d=d \quad c=c \quad b=-2c-d \quad a=-c-d$

so all the possible linear relations between the vectors are:
$$
(-c-d)v_1+(-2c-d)v_2+cv_3+dv_4=0 \quad c,d \in \mathbb{R}
$$